# Is it possible to set the width of a table to "auto" in CSS but acknowledge a width attribute?

Tags: html, css

This is a bit of a strange question, but a rather specific case. I'm trying to shoe-horn modern styles into a legacy website. Part of the issue is the CSS reset that's part of the new styles, which includes this piece of CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

In the legacy website, they didn't have this style and have styled the website assuming that a table will shrink-to-fit. On the surface, this is a simple addition to a transitional style sheet:

```
table {
    width: auto;
}
```

However, every now and again, the table elements have a `width` attribute. Without any CSS applied, this attribute is respected but as soon as the CSS "fix" is applied, the tables reduce in size to their minimum.

I can write some JavaScript to detect tables that have a width attribute and use that to define their styles, but I'm curious: is there a way to do it in pure CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude based on an attribute using `:not()`:

Link to demo : http://tinker.io/8e18e/0

```
/* styles for tables with no "width" attribute */
table:not([width]) {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Of course! Instead of adding that to the transitional style sheet, I tweaked the reset so it sets any table without a width attribute to 100% wide. Thanks for reminding me about `:not()`

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS has no way to say "Use the obsolete presentational attribute that this property replaces" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Remove the `width` attribute and define their widths using CSS instead of a deprecated attribute.  Add some sane table classes, and give those classes the widths you're expecting.

Comment: I'm sure that's the OP's intent, but it doesn't help much during the transitioning phase.

Answer (score 0):

you could for test change display of table, to not have to set width and deal with padding, margin or box-sizing.
http://tinker.io/8e18e/1

```
table {
    display:block;
    background:gray;
}
td, tr {
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
}
table[width], tr {
    border: 1px solid;
    table-layout:fixed;
    display:table;
}
```